# apolloClient read query returns undefined when data is available in cache

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am reading cached data from Apollo client after `client.query` is complete and data is available in cache.
The `client.query` and `client.readQuery` calls are being in done in different sagas and works correctly in most of cases except when url route changes.

When the url route changes first saga for querying data is called and then another saga is called, as a side affect, where by I am reading data from cache. At this point `readQuery` returns `undefined`. I have put console.log to check the `cache.extract` and I can see that the data I am looking for is there in the cache. Here are some code snippets:

```
// Saga1: to query data

 const newData =  getApolloClient().query({
    query: AQuery,
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    variables: { objectId:'123' },
  });

  return newData;
```

```
// saga2 to read data

  const result =  getApolloClient().readQuery({
    query: AQuery,
    variables: { objectId:'123' },
  });

// below prints the cached data I am expecting to get from read query
console.log(">>>>>>", getApolloClient().cache.extract())
```

Can someone please suggest why would `readQuery` return undefined when data is available inc cache?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't Apollo query async? I don't see you waiting for the result or looking at the 'loading' state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply both `getApolloClient().query` and `getApolloClient().readQuery `are in utility function being called by `yield call` hence the code will wait for `Promise` to finish. I skipped the utility function in above code snippet. 
Also I can see the data from `query` being available in UI before `readQuery` is being called.  Moreover if I do `readQuery` just after `query` function (in same saga, just to debug) then I can see readQuery working correctly.

Comment: Is the data there in general, or do you already see this specific query in the ROOT_QUERY field in your `cache.extract` call?

Comment: I see the this specific query (that I am expecting `readQuery` to return) in the ROOT_QUERY in `cache.extract` call.

Comment: @reactdesign in that case, could you please create a reproduction and open an issue over at the Apollo Client GitHub repo?